# Very simple async MixpanelAPI

Tags: java, multithreading, api, asynchronous

I would love to hear feedback on my [first open source project](https://github.com/eranation/mixpanel-java) (a very simple async API for Mixpanel).

It implements a REST client for [this REST HTTP API](https://mixpanel.com/docs/api-documentation/http-specification-insert-data).

**Review requested on the following aspects:**

- Code style (formatting, naming etc...)
- Code quality (best practices, performance etc)
- Asynchronous aspects (usage of `Executors` etc)
- JavaDoc quality

Also I would love to hear feedback on the "non-code" aspects of it

- Github aspects ([readme](https://github.com/eranation/mixpanel-java/blob/master/README.md), license, folder structure)
- Maven aspects ([pom.xml](https://github.com/eranation/mixpanel-java/blob/master/pom.xml) structure and best practices)

**Here is the core code:**

```
package org.eranmedan.mixpanel;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLDecoder;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.helpers.NOPLogger;

import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;

/**
 * A dead simple Mixpanel track API for Java
 * <p>
 * <b>Example Usage:</b>
 * </p>
 * 
 * <blockquote>
 * 
 * <pre>
 * 
 * String uniqueId = &quot;50479b24671bf&quot;;
 * String nameTag = &quot;Test Name&quot;;
 * String ip = &quot;123.123.123.123&quot;;
 * Date time = new Date();
 * String token = &quot;e3bc4100330c35722740fb8c6f5abddc&quot;;
 * Map&lt;String, String&gt; props = new HashMap&lt;String, String&gt;();
 * props.put(&quot;action&quot;, &quot;play&quot;);
 * Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(&quot;MixpanelAPI Test Logger&quot;);
 * 
 * MixpanelAPI mixpanelAPI = new MixpanelAPI(token, logger);
 * 
 * mixpanelAPI.track(&quot;test1&quot;, uniqueId, props);
 * mixpanelAPI.track(&quot;test2&quot;, uniqueId, nameTag, ip, time, props);
 * mixpanelAPI.track(&quot;test3&quot;, uniqueId, nameTag, ip, time);
 * mixpanelAPI.track(&quot;test4&quot;, uniqueId, nameTag, ip);
 * mixpanelAPI.track(&quot;test5&quot;, uniqueId, nameTag);
 * mixpanelAPI.track(&quot;test6&quot;, uniqueId);
 * 
 * 
 * 
 * </pre>
 * 
 * </blockquote>
 * 
 * <b>For example, <code>test2</code> will send a message of this format:</b>
 * 
 * <pre>
 * {   "event": "test2", 
 *     "properties": {
 *         "distinct_id": "50479b24671bf", 
 *         "ip": "123.123.123.123", 
 *         "token": "e3bc4100330c35722740fb8c6f5abddc", 
 *         "time": 1245613885,
 *         "mp_name_tag": "Test Name",  
 *         "action": "play"
 *         
 *     }
 * }
 * </pre>
 * 
 * <b>Note:</b> In most use cases you can ignore the return value of the
 * <code>Future</code> returned for performance. The Future is mostly for
 * testing purposes
 * 
 * @version 0.1
 * @author Eran Medan
 * @see <a
 *      href="https://mixpanel.com/docs/api-documentation/http-specification-insert-data">https://mixpanel.com/docs/api-documentation/http-specification-insert-data</a>
 */
public class MixpanelAPI {
  private static final String MIXPANEL_API_ENDPOINT = "http://api.mixpanel.com/track/?data=";
  private final String token;
  private final Logger logger;
  private final ExecutorService threadPool;

  /**
   * @see #MixpanelAPI(String token, Logger logger, ExecutorService threadPool)
   * 
   */
  public MixpanelAPI(String token) {
    this(token, null);
  }

  /**
   * @see #MixpanelAPI(String token, Logger logger, ExecutorService threadPool)
   * 
   */
  public MixpanelAPI(String token, Logger logger) {
    // TODO: isn't a fixed threadpool based on
    // Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() better?
    this(token, logger, Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
  }

  /**
   * Create a new MixpanelAPI object (usually, there is no need for more than
   * one)
   * 
   * @param token
   *          the MixPanel API token
   * @param logger
   *          an optional Logger, if none provided a {@link NOPLogger} is
   *          provided
   * @param threadPool
   *          an optional custom ExecutorService to queue the asynchronous HTTP
   *          calls to Mixpanel's API, if none provided a
   *          <code>Executors.newCachedThreadPool()</code> is used
   */

  public MixpanelAPI(String token, Logger logger, ExecutorService threadPool) {
    this.token = token;
    this.logger = (logger == null) ? NOPLogger.NOP_LOGGER : logger;
    this.threadPool = threadPool;
  }

  /**
   * @see #track(String event, String nameTag, HttpServletRequest request,
   *      String cookieName, Map additionalProperties)
   */
  public void track(String event, String nameTag, HttpServletRequest request, String cookieName) {
    track(event, nameTag, request, cookieName, null);
  }

  /**
   * Track an event
   * 
   * @param request
   *          the request object, will be used to deduce the IP address and
   *          Mixpanel cookie for the unique ID
   * @param cookieName
   *          the mixpanel cookie name, e.g. if this is your setup:
   * 
   *          <pre>
   * mixpanel.init(token, {
   *         cookie_expiration: 365,
   *         cookie_name: "foobar"
   *      }
   * </pre>
   * 
   *          then the cookie name is actually <code>mp_foobar</code>
   * 
   * @see #track(String event, String distinctId, String nameTag, String ip,
   *      Date time, Map additionalProperties)
   */
  public Future<Boolean> track(String event, String nameTag, HttpServletRequest request, String cookieName, Map<String, String> additionalProperties) {
    Cookie mixpanelCookie = findCookieByName(request, cookieName);
    String uniqueId = null;
    String ip = getClientIpAddr(request);
    if (mixpanelCookie != null) {
      String cookieValue = mixpanelCookie.getValue();
      String result;
      try {
        result = URLDecoder.decode(cookieValue, "UTF-8");
      } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
      }
      JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();

      JsonElement mixJason = jp.parse(result);
      uniqueId = mixJason.getAsJsonObject().get("distinct_id").getAsString();
    } else {
      logger.warn("Unique ID for mixpanel cookie name: " + cookieName + " was not found, using IP instead");
      uniqueId = ip;
    }

    return track(event, uniqueId, nameTag, ip, null, null);
  }

  /**
   * @see #track(String event, String distinctId, String nameTag, String ip,
   *      Date time, Map additionalProperties)
   */
  public Future<Boolean> track(String event, String distinctId) {
    return track(event, distinctId, null, null, null, null);
  }

  /**
   * @return
   * @see #track(String event, String distinctId, String nameTag, String ip,
   *      Date time, Map additionalProperties)
   */
  public Future<Boolean> track(String event, String distinctId, Map<String, String> additionalProperties) {
    return track(event, distinctId, null, null, null, additionalProperties);
  }

  /**
   * @see #track(String event, String distinctId, String nameTag, String ip,
   *      Date time, Map additionalProperties)
   */
  public Future<Boolean> track(String event, String distinctId, String nameTag) {
    return track(event, distinctId, nameTag, null, null, null);
  }

  /**
   * @see #track(String event, String distinctId, String nameTag, String ip,
   *      Date time, Map additionalProperties)
   */
  public Future<Boolean> track(String event, String distinctId, String nameTag, String ip) {
    return track(event, distinctId, nameTag, ip, null, null);
  }

  /**
   * @see #track(String event, String distinctId, String nameTag, String ip,
   *      Date time, Map additionalProperties)
   */
  public Future<Boolean> track(String event, String distinctId, String nameTag, String ip, Date time) {
    return track(event, distinctId, nameTag, ip, time, null);
  }

  /**
   * Tracks an event
   * 
   * @param event
   *          the (required) event name
   * @param distinctId
   *          (required) the user's distinct mixpanel ID (usually stored in a
   *          cookie) or any string that uniquely can identify a user. e.g. the
   *          user id.
   * @param nameTag
   *          (optional) is the way to set a name for a given user for our
   *          streams feature. You can set this to any string value like an
   *          email, first and last name, or username.
   * @param ip
   *          (optional) is a raw string IP Address (e.g. "127.0.0.1") that you
   *          pass to our API. This is largely useful if you're making requests
   *          from your backend and would like geolocation processing done on
   *          your requests otherwise it's safe to use the &ip=1 parameter
   *          described in the docs that is outside of the encoded data string.
   * @param time
   *          is the time at which the event occured, it must be a unix
   *          timestamp, requests will be rejected that are 5 days older than
   *          codesent time - this is done for security reasons as your token is
   *          public generally. Format is seconds since 1970, GMT time zone. If
   *          you'd like to import data, you can through a special API for any
   *          event.
   * @param additionalProperties
   *          additional custom properties in a name-value map
   * @return a {@link Future} object returning a Boolean when calling it's
   *         <code>get()</code> method, true means a successful call (at the
   *         moment, true is the only possible return value, any error will
   *         cause an {@link ExecutionException} to be thrown when calling the
   *         future's get method). <b>Note:</b> In most use cases you can ignore
   *         the return value of the <code>Future</code> returned for
   *         performance. The Future is mostly for testing purposes
   */

  public Future<Boolean> track(final String event, final String distinctId, final String nameTag, final String ip, final Date time, final Map<String, String> additionalProperties) {
    return threadPool.submit(new Callable<Boolean>() {
      @Override
      public Boolean call() throws Exception {
        if (event == null) {
          throw new RuntimeException("event field is mandatory");
        }
        if (distinctId == null) {
          throw new RuntimeException("distinctId field is mandatory");
        }
        JsonObject jo = new JsonObject();
        jo.addProperty("event", event);
        JsonObject properties = new JsonObject();
        jo.add("properties", properties);
        properties.addProperty("distinct_id", distinctId);
        if (ip != null) {
          properties.addProperty("ip", ip);
        }
        properties.addProperty("token", token);
        if (time != null) {
          properties.addProperty("time", time.getTime() / 1000L);
        }
        if (nameTag != null) {
          properties.addProperty("mp_name_tag", nameTag);
        }
        if (additionalProperties != null) {
          for (Entry<String, String> entry : additionalProperties.entrySet()) {
            properties.addProperty(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
          }
        }
        final String message = jo.toString();
        byte[] bytes = message.getBytes();
        String encode = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(bytes);

        logger.debug("Mixpanel message to be sent: " + message);
        final String url = MIXPANEL_API_ENDPOINT + encode;
        logger.debug("Mixpanel URL to call: " + url);
        URL apiURL;

        try {
          apiURL = new URL(url);
          HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) apiURL.openConnection();
          int statusCode = connection.getResponseCode();
          InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
          String contentEncoding = connection.getContentEncoding();
          String responseBody = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, contentEncoding);
          if (statusCode == 200) {
            if (responseBody.equals("1")) {
              logger.debug("Mixpanel event reported successfully");
              return true;
            } else {
              String warningMessage = "Mixpanel event not reported successfully. Response Body: " + responseBody + " message: \n" + message + ". url: " + url;
              logger.warn(warningMessage);
              throw new Exception(warningMessage);
            }
          } else {
            String warningMessage = "Mixpanel response not 200: " + statusCode;
            logger.warn(warningMessage);
            throw new Exception(warningMessage);
          }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
          String warningMessage = "Mixpanel URL is malformed: " + e.getMessage();
          logger.warn(warningMessage, e);
          throw new Exception(warningMessage, e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
          String warningMessage = "Mixpanel IO Exception: " + e.getMessage();
          logger.warn(warningMessage, e);
          throw new Exception(warningMessage, e);
        }
      }
    });
  }

  public void close() {
    if (!threadPool.isShutdown()) {
      threadPool.shutdown();
    }
    // no need to threadPool.awaitTermination, let it end when it ends, just
    // stop accepting new tasks.
  }

  public void awaitTermiation(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) {
    try {
      threadPool.awaitTermination(timeout, unit);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      logger.warn("Didn't terminate after " + timeout + " " + unit.toString());
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
    try {
      close();
    } finally {
      super.finalize();
    }
  }

  private static String getClientIpAddr(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String ip = request.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For");
    if (ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {
      ip = request.getHeader("Proxy-Client-IP");
    }
    if (ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {
      ip = request.getHeader("WL-Proxy-Client-IP");
    }
    if (ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {
      ip = request.getHeader("HTTP_CLIENT_IP");
    }
    if (ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {
      ip = request.getHeader("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR");
    }
    if (ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {
      ip = request.getRemoteAddr();
    }
    return ip;
  }

  private static Cookie findCookieByName(HttpServletRequest request, String cookieName) {
    Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
    if (cookies != null) {
      for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
        if (cookie.getName().equals(cookieName)) {
          return cookie;
        }
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Just 2 comments: (1) You could put `if (ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {return xxx;}` in its own method to avoid the code repetition in your `setClientIpAddr` method. (2) Your last `track` method is quite long and would probably benefit from being split in several smaller methods, at least from a readability perspective.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. I'd implement `Closeable`, `AutoCloseable`:

   ```
   public class MixpanelAPI implements Closeable, AutoCloseable {
       ...
   }
   ```

   See: [implements Closeable or implements AutoCloseable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13141382/843804) on Stack Overflow.
2. > ```
   > public MixpanelAPI(String token, Logger logger, ExecutorService threadPool) {
   >   this.token = token;
   >   this.logger = (logger == null) ? NOPLogger.NOP_LOGGER : logger;
   >   this.threadPool = threadPool;
   > }
   > ```

   I'd check nulls here. Allowing to create an object with an invalid state (when `token` or `threadPool` is `null`) does not look a good idea. You'll get a `NullPointerException` later which would be harder to debug. (*The Pragmatic Programmer: From Journeyman to Master* by *Andrew Hunt* and *David Thomas*: *Dead Programs Tell No Lies*; *Effective Java 2nd Edition*, *Item 38: Check parameters for validity*)

   Guava has a nice [`Preconditions`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.html) API for that.
3. > ```
   > public void track(String event, String nameTag, HttpServletRequest request, String cookieName) {
   >     track(event, nameTag, request, cookieName, null);
   > }
   > ```

   I'd create an explanatory variable for the `null` parameter. It would be easier to read, readers don't have to check the called method to figure out what is that `null`.

   ```
   public void track(String event, String nameTag, HttpServletRequest request, String cookieName) {
       Map<String, String> additionalProperties = null;
       track(event, nameTag, request, cookieName, additionalProperties);
   }
   ```

   (*Clean Code* by *Robert C. Martin*, *G19: Use Explanatory Variables*, p296; *Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code by Martin Fowler*, *Introduce Explaining Variable*)
4. You have too many parameters here:

   > ```
   > return track(event, distinctId, null, null, null, additionalProperties);
   > ```

   It's a code smell: Long Parameter List (See *Long Parameter List* in *Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code* by *Martin Fowler*). You could introduce a parameter object.
5. I'd be a little bit more defensive here and set a limit here:

   > ```
   > String responseBody = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, contentEncoding);
   > ```

   If it accidentally returns a 10GB file you probably waste a lot of network bandwidth and get an `OutOufMemoryError` later.
6. > ```
   > JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();
   > ```

   It would deserve a longer variable name. Longer names would make the code more readable since readers don't have to decode the abbreviations every time and when they write/maintain the code don't have to guess which abbreviation the author uses.

   (*Clean Code* by *Robert C. Martin*, *Avoid Mental Mapping*, p25)
7. > ```
   > logger.warn("Unique ID for mixpanel cookie name: " + cookieName + " was not found, using IP instead");
   > ```

   [SLF4J supports `{}`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SLF4J), use that for easier reading and better performance:

   ```
   logger.warn("Unique ID for mixpanel cookie name: {} was not found, using IP instead", cookieName);
   ```
8. > ```
   >    * @return a {@link Future} object returning a Boolean when calling it's
   >    *         <code>get()</code> method, true means a successful call (at the
   >    *         moment, true is the only possible return value, any error will
   >    *         cause an {@link ExecutionException} to be thrown when calling the
   >    *         future's get method). <b>Note:</b> In most use cases you can ignore
   >    *         the return value of the <code>Future</code> returned for
   >    *         performance. The Future is mostly for testing purposes
   > ```

   In that case you could use `Future<Void>` instead.
9. I'd move the `Callable` to a separate class. I think you could extract out some smaller methods for better readability and fulfilling the [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).
10. > ```
    > URL apiURL;
    > try {
    >     apiURL = new URL(url);
    > ```

    The variable declaration could be inside the try block:

    ```
    try {
        URL apiURL = new URL(url);
    ```
11. > ```
    > InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
    > ```

    You should close this stream in a `finally` block or use try-with-resources. See *Guideline 1-2: Release resources in all cases* in [Secure Coding Guidelines for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/seccodeguide-139067.html)
12. > ```
    > if (statusCode == 200) {
    >     if (responseBody.equals("1")) {
    >         logger.debug("Mixpanel event reported successfully");
    >         return true;
    >     } else {
    >         String warningMessage = "Mixpanel event not reported successfully. Response Body: "
    >                 + responseBody + " message: \n" + message + ". url: " + url;
    >         logger.warn(warningMessage);
    >         throw new Exception(warningMessage);
    >     }
    > } else {
    >     String warningMessage = "Mixpanel response not 200: " + statusCode;
    >     logger.warn(warningMessage);
    >     throw new Exception(warningMessage);
    > }
    > ```

    I think it would be easier to follow with [guard clauses](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/01/flattening-arrow-code.html):

    ```
    if (statusCode != 200) {
        ...
        throw new Exception(warningMessage);
    }
    if (!responseBody.equals("1")) {
        ...
        throw new Exception(warningMessage);
    }
    logger.debug("Mixpanel event reported successfully");
    return true;
    ```
13. > ```
    > if (ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {
    >     ip = request.getHeader("Proxy-Client-IP");
    > }
    > ```

    `ip.length()` could be changed to `ip.isEmpty()`. It's more readable. Furthermore, the first two conditions could be changed to [`StringUtils.isEmpty(ip)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isEmpty%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) (which is null-safe, from [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/)).
14. You have five identical if statements here. I'd remove the duplication and changed it into a loop:

    ```
    private static String getClientIpAddr(HttpServletRequest request) {
        List<String> ipHeaders = newArrayList();
        ipHeaders.add("X-Forwarded-For");
        ipHeaders.add("Proxy-Client-IP");
        ipHeaders.add("WL-Proxy-Client-IP");
        ipHeaders.add("HTTP_CLIENT_IP");
        ipHeaders.add("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR");

        for (String ipHeader: ipHeaders) {
            String ip = request.getHeader(ipHeader);
            boolean validIp = StringUtils.isNotEmpty(ip) && !"unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip);
            if (validIp) {
                return ip;
            }
        }
        return request.getRemoteAddr();
    }
    ```

    (`newArrayList` from [Google Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/).)